# Splitting data from text file in C#

Tags: c#, filestream

How can I split data from a text file, for example, I have this text file

```
"tarek 5235263463 US"
```

in C++ it would be like

```
    string name , number , location;
    file >> name >> number >> location;
```

How can I do the same in C#?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at the [C# documentation for string splitting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you already have the file content as a string (it shouldn't be too difficult to achieve that, should it?). Then you'll first have to split the string:

```
var splitted = inputString.Split();
```

The splitted string now contains the information you want, so all you need to do now is:

```
var name = splitted[0];
var number = splitted[1];
var location = splitted[2];
```

That should do what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

Use `string.Split(char[], StringSplitOptions);` The char[] parameter lets you split on multiple characters if you so desire. See documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
List<string> fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\filepath.txt").ToList();

foreach(var fileLine in fileLines)
{
    var splitFileLine = fileLine.Split(new[] {" "}, StringSplitOptions.None);

    var name = splitFileLine[0];
    var number = splitFileLine[1];
    var location = splitFileLine[2];

    //save, output, whatever you want 
}
```

Comment: Did you actually compile this code? You closed the bracket `}` too late.

Comment: @MetaColon. No, I did not. You are correct, I misplaced the }. I write out most of my answer using Notepad++ so I don't always catch issues along those lines.